# How to match X number of whole words in separate groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently trying to match X number of words on each side of a search term with three matching groups including the X number of words before the term, the term, the X number of words after the term.

It is worth noting I need this regex to work in Javascript.

For example, if my full string is:
"Hello this is a long sentence with a matching word somewhere"

If my X number for words to match on each side was 2 and my search term was "sentence", I would like my regex matches to return:

- group 1: "a long "
- group 2: "sentence"
- group 3: " with a"

I've tried using parens to form groups, as well as the `\w` shorthand to match whole words.

This gets me pretty close, matches everything i want, but just does not break up the matches into 3 separate groups.

```
(\w+ ){0,2}(string)( \w+){0,2}
```

The string to test against: 
`this is my long string and i know what it is`

Expected Results:

- group 1: "my long "
- group 2: "string"
- group 3: " and i"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to capture the `(\w+ ){0,2}` in one group and same with `( \w+){0,2}`. Something like `/((?:\w+ ){0,2})(string)((?: \w+){0,2})/` or `/((?:\w+\s){0,2})(string)((?:\s\w+){0,2})/`.

Example:

```js
var string = "this is my long string and i know what it is";
console.log(string.match(/((?:\w+\s){0,2})(string)((?:\s\w+){0,2})/));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have only one word in a capturing group and then you're repeating the group, thus, only the last occurrence will be placed in the capturing group. You need to put the one word in a non-capturing group and then put the X words in the capturing group.

Try something like this:

```regex
((?:\w+[ ]){2})(string)((?:[ ]\w+){2})
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UZiCpI/1).

**Javascript example:**

```js
const regex = /((?:\w+[ ]){2})(string)((?:[ ]\w+){2})/gm;
const str = `this is my long string and i know what it is`;

let m = regex.exec(str);
m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
  console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
});
```

Obviously, this will only match exactly two words before and after the target string (as you described). If you actually intended to match two words or less (as your pattern indicates), you may use `{0,2}` instead of `{2}`.